# Node Run script from IDE Fails No "exports" main defined

Tags: node.js, npm, ipfs, ipfs-http-client

I'm trying to create a project which deploys nfts to ipfs automatically.  I downloaded an existing project and I'm trying to extend the functionality

My `packages.json` looks like so:

```
{
  "name": "3_market_engine",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": "index.js",
  "pkg": {
    "assets": [
      "layers/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "src/**/*"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node index.js",
    "generate": "node index.js",
    "generate_metadata": "node utils/generate_metadata.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
      "canvas": "^2.8.0",
      "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
      "gif-encoder-2": "^1.0.5",
      "ipfs-http-client": "^59.0.0",
      "sha1": "^1.1.1"
 }
```

I can run the `npm run generate_metadata` command just fine however whenever I try to add a require statement to `const { ipfsClient } = require('ipfs-http-client');` to the file I get an
error:

> Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in C:\source\3_market_nft_engine\node_modules\ipfs-http-client\package.json
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
> at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:358:9)
> at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:612:7)
> at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:529:36)
> at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:569:31)
> at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
> at Object. (C:\source\3_market_nft_engine\utils\generate_metadata.js:4:20) {
> code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
> }

I've tried:

1. Changing my version of node
2. Reinstalling the packages
3. Using yarn instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is no `main` in that package's `package.json` (https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/packages/ipfs-http-client/package.json). Per [this note in the changelog](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/upgrading/v0.62-v0.63.md#esm), the package is meant to be used with ESM, but that also wouldn't fix your problem because there's no export called `ipfsClient`; you need `import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client'`.

Edit: as noted in your comment, downgrading to a version from before the package switched to ESM also works. Details in the comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new to node development
I just tried what you stated: `import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client'` and I also tried `const { create } = require('ipfs-http-client');` I'm getting the same error

Comment: Did you add `type: module` to your package.json? Or if that's not doable in your code base, does using the async import method in the changelog linked above work for you?

Comment: I'm pretty vanilla still I'm not sure what ESM is and type:module but ill do some research

Comment: I got it working using `npm i ipfs-http-client@50.1.2 @babel /core --save`

Comment: Not sure why it works but if you add it to your answer I'll mark it as correct or maybe you can help explain

Comment: Downgrading the version worked because the older version used commonjs modules. I would recommend reading a bit about Ecmascript Modules vs CommonJS, but basically Node used to use its own system for modules (require/module.exports), and everyone's been gradually transitioning their packages to ESM (import/export) since around 2015 when it became a part of the language standard.